# Two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov plot in R (using raw data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm interested in replicating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162178/kolmogorov-smirnov-plot-in-r-ggplot) plot (two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov plot) for my data, but they use a "rnorm" example. Is this possible to do with raw data (preferably in ggplot as well)? I can't seem to replicate the variables using the ecdf and cdf1 functions (possibly because of duplicate values and/or small sample sizes(?).

My data:

```
> dry_2006 <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, dry_2006)
> class(dry_2006)
[1] "data.frame"
> dput(dry_2006)
structure(list(CYR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("2006", "2015", "2016", 
"2018"), class = "factor"), Month = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), temp = c(18.66, 
21.36, 25.03, 21.58, 19.24, 19.32, 23.6, 25.57, 21.95, 24.9, 
19.48, 25.82, 25.15, 23.04, 24.18, 22.85, 19.79, 25.72, 25.29, 
23.82, 23.9, 23.37, 20.55, 26.04, 25.88, 24.51, 24.02, 21, 23.79, 
27.16, 26.97, 24.93, 24.17, 23.66, 22.13, 28.06, 27.37, 25.89, 
28.09, 26.83, 25.52, 28.3, 26.58, 28.94, 26.3, 26.48, 24.46)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-47L))
```

Comment: `rnorm` in the answer is meant to simulate raw data. There's nothing special about it otherwise.

Comment: Raw data was a poor word choice. My data isn't normally distributed I guess, rnorm is a random sample from a normal distribution, correct?

Comment: Not simulated (real) data, perhaps.

Comment: I do have a similar code for the KS test on my personal laptop, I can give you that once I get home tonight. It might help.

Comment: @Nate the KS test does work with non-Gaussian data, if that helps clarify things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: Oh, yes I know it does. I just wasn't sure how to adjust the script to use my own data rather than simulated data. Thank you though.

Comment: So what are your two samples? `temp` and?

Comment: The two levels of the Month factor are my two samples for the variable temp (temperature for February and March). Small sample sizes I know, but it’s all I’ve got unfortunately.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, any luck finding the code?

Comment: Yes, I did find it, but based on your data, it will require some modification. I basically created a function to run a two sample KS test for each month.

Comment: I am in office right now, so I don't have my personal laptop with me at the moment. Once I get back home, I can start working on those code changes and get back to you. Will that work?

Comment: Also can you do me a small favor, can you convert your data to a dataframe which is not a list?

Comment: Of course, no rush! Like this (changed content in question)?

Comment: Once your data is not in the list form, your final columns could be something like `Year`, `TempFeb` and `TempMar`.

Comment: Yes, that would work thank you, and then `TempFeb` and `TempMar` will be the columns used as the two variables/samples in the code.